# Lightbox2 Swipe gesture for touchscreens

Tags: jquery-ui, lightbox2

To my great surprise Lightbox2(http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) does not support swipe gestures out of the box...

I was not able to find any add on in order to support this behavior. Anyone has any suggestions a side from changing the entire plugin? :)

Answer (score 1):

To summary, you must hide the navigation buttons and implement swiping, moving and sliding effect on the image.

You will need :

- [jquery.event.move](https://github.com/stephband/jquery.event.move/archive/master.zip)
- [jquery.event.swipe](https://github.com/stephband/jquery.event.swipe/archive/master.zip)
- jquery ui slide effect, you can package it in the [jquery ui download builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

maybe there's a simplest way to get/implement all of these 3 small dependencies... but that way works for me.

in the lightbox script, add a new LightboxOptions `enableSwipeOnTouchDevices` and set it to true :

```
this.enableSwipeOnTouchDevices   = true;
```

add the following blocks after the `this.$lightbox.find('.lb-next').on('click'...` block to create the swiping events:

```
this.$lightbox.find('.lb-image').on("swiperight",function() {
    $('.lb-image').effect("slide", { "direction" : "right",  "mode" : "hide"} ,function(){
        if (self.currentImageIndex === 0) {
          self.changeImage(self.album.length - 1);
        } else {
          self.changeImage(self.currentImageIndex - 1);
        }
    })
});


this.$lightbox.find('.lb-image').on("swipeleft",function() {  
    $('.lb-image').effect("slide", { "direction" : "left",  "mode" : "hide"} ,function(){
        if (self.currentImageIndex === self.album.length - 1) {
          self.changeImage(0);
        } else {
          self.changeImage(self.currentImageIndex + 1);
        }
    })
});
```

and rewrite the `updateNav` function like this to hide the navigation buttons:

```
Lightbox.prototype.updateNav = function() {
  // Check to see if the browser supports touch events. If so, we take the conservative approach
  // and assume that mouse hover events are not supported and always show prev/next navigation
  // arrows in image sets.
  var alwaysShowNav = false;
  var enableSwipe = false;
  try {
    document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
    alwaysShowNav = (this.options.alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices)? true: false;
    enableSwipe =  (this.options.enableSwipeOnTouchDevices)? true: false;
  } catch (e) {}


    //if swiping is enable, hide the two navigation buttons
    if (! enableSwipe) {
      this.$lightbox.find('.lb-nav').show();

      if (this.album.length > 1) {
        if (this.options.wrapAround) {
          if (alwaysShowNav) {
            this.$lightbox.find('.lb-prev, .lb-next').css('opacity', '1');
          }
          this.$lightbox.find('.lb-prev, .lb-next').show();
        } else {
          if (this.currentImageIndex > 0) {
            this.$lightbox.find('.lb-prev').show();
            if (alwaysShowNav) {
              this.$lightbox.find('.lb-prev').css('opacity', '1');
            }
          }
          if (this.currentImageIndex < this.album.length - 1) {
            this.$lightbox.find('.lb-next').show();
            if (alwaysShowNav) {
              this.$lightbox.find('.lb-next').css('opacity', '1');
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
};
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you considered submitting this as a patch to the original project? It would help out a lot of folks and would close issue https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/233

Answer (score 0):

I've used jquery mobile to detect `swipeleft` and `swiperight`. Then bind them to click `.lb-next` and `.lb-prev`. It's working now.

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/sundowatch/pen/RwNdaNV).

Answer (score 0):

PEC's solution worked for me with one modification on a Jekyll site.

Instead of:
this.enableSwipeOnTouchDevices   = true;

We added this to /_includes/scripts.html after the dependencies and lightbox.js:

```
<script>
lightbox.option({
  'enableSwipeOnTouchDevices': true,
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The PEC solution is good, but it doesn't work anymore with the current version of lightbox (2.11.2). The effect() method doesn't exists anymore.

So the swiping methods should be updated:

```
this.$lightbox.find('.lb-image').on("swiperight",function() {
     if (self.currentImageIndex === 0) {
    self.changeImage(self.album.length - 1);
  } else {
    self.changeImage(self.currentImageIndex - 1);
  }
  return false;
});

this.$lightbox.find('.lb-image').on("swipeleft",function() {  
  if (self.currentImageIndex === self.album.length - 1) {
    self.changeImage(0);
  } else {
    self.changeImage(self.currentImageIndex + 1);
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Less fancy, but shorter and works.

In short: 'catch' swipe gesture and then trigger 'click' on next/prev button based on swipe direction.

```
let touchstartX = 0;
let touchendX = 0;  
  
function handleGesture() {
  if (touchendX < touchstartX) $(".lb-prev").trigger("click");
  if (touchendX > touchstartX) $(".lb-next").trigger("click");
}
  
$(document).on("touchstart", ".lb-nav", e => {
  touchstartX = e.changedTouches[0].screenX;
});  

$(document).on("touchend", ".lb-nav", e => {
  touchendX = e.changedTouches[0].screenX;
  handleGesture();
});
```